# YouTube Analytics API | Content Owner Report by State

Tags: javascript, youtube, google-analytics, youtube-api

I am trying to perform this request:

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=contentOwner%3D%myId&start-date=2014-05-01&end-date=2014-06-30&metrics=views&dimensions=province&filters=channel%3D%chanId%3Bcountry%3DUS&sort=-   estimatedMinutesWatched&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

My aim is to generate a content owner report for a given channel that we manage that will return views and earnings information for only US states.

The above returns this error:

```
400 Bad Request

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
   "errors": [
 {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "Could not parse content (N/A) of field parameters.filters."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Could not parse content (N/A) of field parameters.filters."
 }
}
```

I am using the documentation on the API Explorer page and my request appears to be correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you use filters with "=" instead of "==" like "channel==ID"

After that, you will have another problem. I tried same query and it worked with adding estimatedMinutesWatched into views. To use that as sort order, you need to use it in views or dimensions.

Here's my request:

> GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=contentOwner%3D%3DCONTOWNER&start-date=2014-05-01&end-date=2014-06-30&metrics=views%2CestimatedMinutesWatched&dimensions=province&filters=channel%3D%3DUCBLABLA%3Bcountry%3D%3DUS&sort=-estimatedMinutesWatched&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Make sure your request fits one of https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/sample-requests#Content_Owner_Reports

and try it in https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query

Comment: Thanks for the response - I have been using the API explorer exclusively to test this and the value after channel is not chanId it is the actual channel ID so that section looks more like `channel==UCTHERESTOFMYCHANNELID` the query works as long as I dont include a channel filter which is what I want to use and according to this documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/dims#channel I should be able to use the channel ID as a filter.

Comment: found your problem in syntax. You'll have another one after you fix that one. Edited my answer.